# Merging tags [feed] and [feeds]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [feed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed) and [feeds](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds) tags refer to the same thing and thus should be merged.

Qs tagged [feed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed)
Qs tagged [feeds](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done and a synonym created for `feed` > `feeds`